# visualize the duration of events

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I want to visualize durations of events as a bar, my input value is a decimal value where the integer part represents days and the decimal part a fraction of a day. I can convert the input value to any value needed.
An event can span multiple days.
The code below contains data for two events, the duration of event a is 36 hours and the duration of event b is 12 hours. Of course, it's possible that an event can be over after just some minutes or take 3hours 14minutes 24seconds.
I want the x-axis have ticks every 30minutes, from the sample data I need 36 hours, an axis label can look like 0d 0:00.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": "container",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "event": "a",
        "durationdecimal": 1.5
      },
      {
          "event": "b",
        "durationdecimal": 0.5
      }
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "durationdecimal",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"grid": false},
      "timeUnit": "utchoursminutes"
    },
    "y": {"field": "event", "type": "nominal", "title": null}
  ,
  "tooltip": [{"field": "durationdecimal"}]
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your `durationdecimal` should be `temporal` as there is no `date/month/year` provided. I tried recreating your sample using `quantitative` type and have done conversions on labels using `labelExpr` and some [expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/). It mostly covers all your mentioned requirements. The only remaining part seems to be of ticks for 30 mins.

Below is the config or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoMcGmSxoQUOZiQ1ZcAE6KQAdxoATehq2ydew8fNIdaUMSSCGcCGgDaoOFJbDRQlcwYDZ3ZZczgoGmRBNABGSjEAXwUAoMxrRwiouVj4xLQAJkpkzOy4YPQmfMjMaOKEjzQABjT0gF1MkGQDAGtXEEwATxw4DSYkI37MSNkIADM2AwQ-UCgPKAZBZ2n0CBxhTAAKTDYAZUW9MnOnTAYESnCmlri2wQBKBQBySj-H6+Do9AAEAGpwf9zDCoeDziczpcbndZA8ni83gVmkUvok-oDgb5khCAPzglaCNjrc7nf5df6Q5F0VG3Az3R7ObHvQoxAkeIlAkFkn4AKjKABYfgj-qgOh15TCOgqlT9jEgfOgAB4AfSecAAMkgmHBBAAVWmCZo4EC9JS1LTme6jHWjFY0c3mDR8vECkrtJQTKYaACODCQtjoUVImp1NG1oDInJ9qBWHggcCUBzNggAojqcEZjqc2VcOVysa9c+bhSSwXK4f8EUiyxcK+jMTya6a6wCRaSKVSaXSGUyWe32V3uc9e3n66KehLpbLofLFcrGWrgfb+uMPV7BGmQIFarlg5MjiBZGwEHog2M6IIjrJ9oIFtbbVsQJ7vRp9UNE08ytNgbRoO1enSdIgA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": "container",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"event": "a", "durationdecimal": 1.5},
      {"event": "c", "durationdecimal": 2.1},
      {"event": "b", "durationdecimal": 0.5}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "split(toString(datum.durationdecimal),'.')[0] + 'd ' + (split(toString(datum.durationdecimal),'.')[1] ? floor(('0.'+split(toString(datum.durationdecimal),'.')[1])*24) + ':00': '0:00')",
      "as": "x_dateLabelTooltip"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "durationdecimal",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "grid": false,
        "labelExpr": "split(toString(datum.label),'.')[0] + 'd ' + (split(toString(datum.label),'.')[1] ? floor(('0.'+split(toString(datum.label),'.')[1])*24) + ':00': '0:00')"
      }
    },
    "y": {"field": "event", "type": "nominal", "title": null},
    "tooltip": [{"field": "x_dateLabelTooltip"}]
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Whoa! This is exactly what I was looking for.
I will try to get the 30min, if I succeed I will add another comment.
Thanks a lot!